# Ordering Grep Output With Multiple Patterns

Tags: regex, macos, unix, command-line, grep

The file I'm searching (fruit.text) looks something like the below snippet, the data appears in random order that I cannot control.

> ....fruit=apple,...qty=3,...condition=bad,....
>
> ...qty=4,...condition=great,...fruit=orange,...
>
> ...condition=ok,...qty=2,...fruit=banana,...

My Grep command is: `grep -Eo 'fruit.[^,]*'\|'qty.[^,]*'\|'condition.[^,]*' fruit.txt`

This results in output like:

> fruit=apple
>
> qty=3
>
> condition=bad
>
> qty=4
>
> condition=great
>
> fruit=orange
>
> condition=ok
>
> qty=2
>
> fruit=banana

Which is correct, however, I'm looking for the output to be ordered as I specified in the grep cmd. ie, exactly like the below:

> fruit=apple
>
> qty=3
>
> condition=bad
>
> fruit=orange
>
> qty=4
>
> condition=great
>
> fruit=banana
>
> qty=2
>
> condition=ok

Answer (score 1):

A solution with gawk:

first i added some extra ',' to the input:

```
....,fruit=apple,...,qty=3,...,condition=bad,....
...,qty=4,...,condition=great,...,fruit=orange,...
...,condition=ok,...,qty=2,...,fruit=banana,...
```

Then i wrote this awk script (fruit.awk):

```
{ fruit ="";
  qty="";
  condition="";
  for (i = 1;i <= NF; i++){
        delete a;
        split($i,a,"=");
        if (a[1]=="fruit" ) { fruit=a[2]; }
        if (a[1]=="qty") { qty=a[2] }
        if (a[1]=="condition") { condition=a[2] }
   }
}
{ print "fruit=" fruit;
  print "qty=" qty;
  print "condition=" condition;
}
```

output of: `gawk -F , -f fruit.awk fruit.txt`:

```
fruit=apple
qty=3
condition=bad
fruit=orange
qty=4
condition=great
fruit=banana
qty=2
condition=ok
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` in some steps:

```
sed -E 's/^/,/;
        s/(.*),(condition[^,]*)/\2\r,\1/;
        s/(.*),(qty=[^,]*)/\2,\1/;
        s/(.*),(fruit=[^,]*)/\2,\1/;
        s/\r.*//;
        s/,/\n/g' input.txt
```

I start with inserting a `,` for input where the interesting data starts in the first field.
After `condition` I add a `\r`, so I can remove the garbage after finding the fruit.